# Calculation of the fundamental group from triangulations

Tags: algebraic-topology, computational-geometry

Is there - say, for a triangulable surface - a concrete algorithm how to calculate the fundamental group of the surface from a given triangulation, seen as a graph (of its 1-skeleton), given as an adjacency matrix?

If there is such an algorithm: Does *every* triangulation do the job (as an input of the algorithm)?

(Specifically: Which (serious) algorithm gives back the trivial group for input $K_4$ and $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ for input $K_7$?)

Or is this kind of question just too naive?

Comment: What about van Kampen theorem ?

Comment: Van Kampen is an attempt to reduce the given problem to assumably simpler ones. I ask for solutions **from scratch**.

Comment: Won't the Euler characteristic tell you what the surface is?

Comment: @Steve: You are right - and I should close this question. It seems harder - than expected - to even formulate what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_groups#Fundamental_group

This is an algorithm to calculate the fundamental group based on the spanning tree of its triangulations.